# How to allow two input values using an HTML pattern attribute

Tags: html, input

I'm looking to constrain user input using an HTML pattern attribute on a text input, I didn't want to use a select or radio buttons tag for design purposes. I tried many approaches but none of them allowed me to get to what I want.

```html
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" class="study" name="study" placeholder="Enter your year of study L1-3,M1-2 "  pattern="[L-l-M-m]+[1-2-3]" maxlength="2" title="only L1,L2,L3 and M1,M2 are allowed" required>
<button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [L]{1}[1-3]|[M]{1}[1-2] using https://regex101.com and using logical or [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cxRt.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use this pattern: `[LM]{1}[0-9]{1}`

You can check if this work for you with this tool: https://regex101.com

Comment: as i mentioned in the code : title="only L1,L2,L3 and M1,M2 are allowed" , your suggestion even if i edit it , it  allowes M3 :'(